# Cannot access internal (polyglot) libraries from Graal native-image binary

Tags: java, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I've created a simple "hello world" application to introduce myself to Graal and its polyglot functionality (currently linux only).

https://github.com/BurntMonkey/hello-graal/

To be honest, it's a bit hacky - but it's relatively clean nonetheless.

I'm compiling the c code to a shared object (.so) and placing it in the resources directory.

I've installed the LLVM toolchain as well as native-image with Graal's gu command.

With $JAVA_HOME pointing to that Graal instance, the jar works as expected.

I compiled that to a native image with the following command:

```
$GRAAL_HOME/bin/native-image -H:IncludeResources="lib/.+" --language:llvm -jar hellograal-1.0.jar
```

Compilation completes (takes a long time, but that's expected) but execution fails with the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" Cannot load "libsulong-native.so". Internal library path not set
     at org.graalvm.sdk/org.graalvm.polyglot.Context.eval(Context.java:399)
     at NativeApp.main(NativeApp.java:14)
```

I've spent some time trying to figure out how to define the internal library path, to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The error occurs with the current release version of GraalVM (22.3), but is resolved in the current development version (23.0.0).</strike>

Closing as answered.

The version compiled by the dev build can run, but only from the target directory.

Should really have checked that sooner.